# Transition property affecting other elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

So recently I have started to learn Web Dev and I seem to face the following problem very often with the transition property.

Here is the code:

https://codepen.io/utkarsh-kumar384/pen/qBZPxPb

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Python_Scripts/static/css/add.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post">

      <div class="flex-items">
        <input type="text" name="Rate" required="" />
        <label class="label-placeholder">
          <span>input text 1</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-items">
        <input type="text" name="JrlNo" required="" />
        <label class="label-placeholder">
          <span>a very long input text </span>
        </label>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  --abel: "Abel", sans-serif;
  --Open-sans: "Open-Sans", "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
}

form{
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 45%;
  min-height: 45%;
  max-height: 45%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f83600 0%, #f9d423 100%);
}

.container {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.flex-items {
  margin: 10px;
}

.label-placeholder {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.label-placeholder span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8vh;
  left: 6px;
  transition: ease-in 0.19s;
  font-family: var(--abel);
  font-size: 1.15em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"] {
  color: #595f6e;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.flex-items input[type="text"]:focus + .label-placeholder span,
.flex-items input[type="text"]:valid + .label-placeholder span {
  bottom: 16vh;
  left: 0;
  font-family: var(--Open-sans);
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"]:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}
```

So my problem is that whenever I click different input fields, the form height seems to change in a very subtle manner. Is there any way to set a fixed form height so that it won't move?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I face this issue with other elements as well. Not only in forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements change their sizes, and it makes their container to also change its size.

You need two little adjustments:

First, fix the height of the placeholders:

```
.label-placeholder {
       height: 25px;
       display: block;
    }
```

Then, add a transparent border to the input fields when the black border is invisible:

```
.flex-items input[type="text"] {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"]:invalid {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-color: black;
}
```

Overall snippet:

```css
:root {
  --abel: "Abel", sans-serif;
  --Open-sans: "Open-Sans", "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
}

form{
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 45%;
  min-height: 45%;
  max-height: 45%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f83600 0%, #f9d423 100%);
}

.container {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.flex-items {
  margin: 10px;
}

.label-placeholder {
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
}

.label-placeholder span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8vh;
  left: 6px;
  transition: ease-in 0.19s;
  font-family: var(--abel);
  font-size: 1.15em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"] {
  color: #595f6e;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.flex-items input[type="text"]:focus + .label-placeholder span,
.flex-items input[type="text"]:valid + .label-placeholder span {
  bottom: 16vh;
  left: 0;
  font-family: var(--Open-sans);
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"]:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.flex-items input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-color: black;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post">

      <div class="flex-items">
        <input type="text" name="Rate" required="" />
        <label class="label-placeholder">
          <span>input text 1</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-items">
        <input type="text" name="JrlNo" required="" />
        <label class="label-placeholder">
          <span>a very long input text </span>
        </label>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank You It's working Flawlessly :)) and can you tell me how to avoid this from happening in future?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code on your form.

```
form {
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 45%;
    min-height: 45%;
    max-height: 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works!! Thanks a lot and Can you tell me how to avoid this from happening in the future?

Comment: When using max-width or height it's good practice to set how long the container or element will be. Just set the max-width or height with a corresponding px then you can declare it's height or width with the percentage you want and it will automatically resize.

Comment: Oh okay Thanks :))

Comment: Setting the exact heights of containers is generally a bad idea. It is very difficult to maintain on big projects, and often tends to break across different browsers/settings.